# Increment through property names in object

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have the following object:

```
namespace BluetoothExample
{
    public class Assay
    {
        public double Band_1 //Vis450
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public double Band_2 //Vis500
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public double Band_3 //Vis550
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public double Band_4 //Vis570
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to populate the 4 bands in my object. Which I currently do in the following way:

```
public Populate()
{
    int _i = 0;
    double[] nirData = new double[4];
        MyDevice.Characteristic.ValueUpdated += (sender, e) =>
        {
            nirData[_i] = BitConverter.ToDouble(e.Characteristic.Value, 0);
            _i++;
        };
    Assay assay = new Assay();
    assay.Band_1 = nirData[0];
    assay.Band_2 = nirData[1];
    assay.Band_3 = nirData[2];
    assay.Band_4 = nirData[3];
}
```

I was wondering if it was possible to do the entire thing inside the `MyDevice.Characteristic.ValueUpdate` method instead? My thought is that it should be possible to increment and populate the properties of my object like so:

```
string name = "assay.Band_" + _i;
name = BitConverter.ToDouble(e.Characteristic.Value, 0);
```

This is obviously wrong, but it sort of demonstrates my idea.

Comment: Why not use a List or array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make your band an Array, or List:

```
public class Assay
{
     public double[] Band 
     {
          get;
          set;
     }
}
```

And then you can simply assign it like:

```
public Populate()
{
    int _i = 0;
    double[] nirData = new double[4];
        MyDevice.Characteristic.ValueUpdated += (sender, e) =>
        {
            nirData[_i] = BitConverter.ToDouble(e.Characteristic.Value, 0);
            _i++;
        };
    Assay assay = new Assay();
    assay.Band = nirData;
}
```